# rails controller.controller_name empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I try to define my HTML body class (in application.html.erb), using the current controller name.

This way :

```
<body class='<% controller.controller_name %>'>
```

But I always have an empty body class

Generated HTML :

```
<body class="">
```

Why is controller.controller_name empty in application ? Or is there another way to proceed?

I used rails 3.2.13.

Comment: Seems you forgot to add `=` after opening of erb block. This should work: `<%= controller.controller_name %>`.

Comment: Also, you do not have to write controller.controller_name, <%= controller_name %> will give you the same result.

Comment: Thanks, = works much better !

Comment: @MikhailD you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from comments:

Seems you forgot to add `=` after opening of erb block. This should work:

`<%= controller.controller_name %>`

Also, you do not have to write `controller.controller_name`, `<%= controller_name %>` will give you the same result.